# Trying to copy VS solution from one Azure DevOps remote repo to a new one

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

This is probably VERY simple, but my searching hasn't found me a solution yet.

Simply put. I have a VS 2019 Solution that is using an Azure DevOps repo. I need to make a complete duplicate of the solution (due to a compliance requirement that the two code bases remain separate) but with no history, etc. Just a clean 2nd repo.

I'm not sure if the answer is to make a copy of the solution on my local machine (without the .git folder) and then push it to the new depo, or is there a better way, since that doesn't seem to work using VS to manage the connections to the repo.

Comment: If you don't want to share history, then yes, just simply copy, commit, and push.

Comment: Probably best to have something in the initial commit message for the new copy saying something to the effect of "Splitting from $REPO at $SHA for compliance reasons", but otherwise, yeah, copy/commit/push.

Comment: How would you recommend I do the commit? Using VS, just pointing at the new empty repo doesn't show any files in the solution explorer.

Comment: Maybe uncompress of the archive you get using `git archive -o head.tar HEAD` could be a good idea to ensure you have just and all the files needed https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#_examples